# Java TreeView issue in linux

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, iterable

I'm trying to create a file manager inside an app I am developing. This file manager uses TreeView and TreeItem, but  I am stuck on getting the root folder.
 [I hope this image let me explain better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQfPJ.png).
This is the main class:

```
public class JavaFXFileBrowseDemoApp extends Application {
private TreeView<String> treeView;

public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    //create tree pane
    VBox treeBox=new VBox();
    treeBox.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
    treeBox.setSpacing(10);
    //setup the file browser root
    String hostName="computer";

    try{
        hostName=InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException x){}

    TreeItem<String> rootNode = new TreeItem<>(hostName, new ImageView(FilePathTreeItem.computer)); // FilePathTreeItem.computer is just an image

    Iterable<Path> rootDirectories = FileSystems.getDefault().getRootDirectories();

    for(Path name : rootDirectories){
        System.out.println(name.getFileName()); // <----- it gives me null
        FilePathTreeItem treeNode=new FilePathTreeItem(name);
        rootNode.getChildren().add(treeNode);
    }


    rootNode.setExpanded(true);
    //create the tree view
    treeView=new TreeView<>(rootNode);
    //add everything to the tree pane
    treeBox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("File browser"),treeView);
    VBox.setVgrow(treeView,Priority.ALWAYS);

    //setup and show the window
    primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX File Browse Demo");
    StackPane root=new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(treeBox);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root,400,300));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

}

Here there is the FilePathTreeItem class:

```
public class FilePathTreeItem extends TreeItem<String>{
public static Image computer = new Image(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("computer.png"));
public static Image folderClosed = new Image(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("folder-closed.png"));
public static Image folderOpened = new Image(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("folder-opened.png"));
public static Image genericText= new Image(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("generic-text.png"));

private String fullPath;
private boolean isDirectory;

public FilePathTreeItem(Path file){
    super(file.toString());
    fullPath = file.toString();

    // test if this is a directory and set the icon
    if (Files.isDirectory(file)){
        isDirectory = true;
        setGraphic(new ImageView(folderClosed));
    }
    else{
        isDirectory = false;

        if (file.endsWith("txt")){
            setGraphic(new ImageView(genericText));
        }
    }

    if(!fullPath.endsWith(File.separator)){
        String value = file.toString();
        int indexOf = value.lastIndexOf(File.separator);

        if (indexOf > 0){
            setValue(value.substring(indexOf + 1));
        }
        else{
            setValue(value);
        }
    }

    this.addEventHandler(TreeItem.<Object>branchExpandedEvent(), new EventHandler(){
        @Override
        public void handle(Event e){
            FilePathTreeItem source = (FilePathTreeItem)e.getSource();
            if (source.isDirectory() && source.isExpanded()){
                ImageView iv = (ImageView)source.getGraphic();
                iv.setImage(folderOpened);
            }

            try{
                if (source.getChildren().isEmpty()){
                    Path path = Paths.get(source.getFullPath());
                    BasicFileAttributes attribs = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
                    if (attribs.isDirectory()){
                        DirectoryStream<Path> dir = Files.newDirectoryStream(path);

                        for(Path file : dir){
                            FilePathTreeItem treeNode = new FilePathTreeItem(file);
                            source.getChildren().add(treeNode);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    //if you want to implement rescanning a directory for changes this would be the place to do it
                }
            }
            catch(IOException x){
                x.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    this.addEventHandler(TreeItem.<Object>branchCollapsedEvent(), new EventHandler(){
        @Override
        public void handle(Event e){
            FilePathTreeItem source = (FilePathTreeItem) e.getSource();
            if (source.isDirectory() && !source.isExpanded()){
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) source.getGraphic();
                iv.setImage(folderOpened);
            }
        }
    });
}

public String getFullPath() {
    return fullPath;
}

public boolean isDirectory() {
    return isDirectory;
}
```

}

Comment: What is the actual question? Is it "Why is [`Path.getFileName()` returning `null`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName--)"?

Comment: not only that, the problem is that it doesn't create any clickable and expandable folder (i think it's due to FileSystems.getDefault().getRootDirectories())

Comment: I think you really need to create an [MCVE] for this, and explain the issue better. So remove all the resource-based stuff (i.e. images) and create an executable example which demonstrates the same problem, and which people can run. Otherwise it's pretty much impossible to know why it is not working.

Comment: As far as I can see, you never add any child nodes to the tree items representing the root directory. This means the tree will treat this as a leaf node, so it won't be expandable. Have a look at the second example in the [`TreeItem` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html) to see how to get around that.

Comment: my problem is this: Iterable<Path> rootDirectories = FileSystems.getDefault().getRootDirectories(); because it doesn't allow me to explore and expand directories and files

Comment: I answered that in the previous comment.

Comment: i followed this example: http://huguesjohnson.com/programming/java/javafx-treeview-browser/ but it doesn't work as it should

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the source code for his example... and it doesn't work. Again, because there are no child items in the tree item, so `isLeaf()` returns `true`, so the UI doesn't give an option to expand the node. You need to use code similar to that in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code (and indeed the example you based it on) do not work because no child nodes are added to the tree item until it is expanded. However, a JavaFX `TreeItem` cannot be expanded if it is a leaf node, and the definition of leaf node is one that has no child nodes. So you never get a chance to expand the node, and it never gets populated.

You need to do something along the lines of:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class FilePathTreeItem extends TreeItem<String>{
    public static Image computer = new Image(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("computer.png"));
    public static Image folderClosed = new Image(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("folder.png"));
    public static Image folderOpened = new Image(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("folder-open.png"));
    public static Image genericText= new Image(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("text-x-generic.png"));

    private ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

    private String fullPath;
    private boolean isDirectory;

    private boolean isFirstTimeLeaf = true ;
    private boolean isFirstTimeChildren = true ;
    private boolean isLeaf ;    

    public FilePathTreeItem(Path file){
        super(file.toString());
        fullPath = file.toString();

        // test if this is a directory and set the icon
        if (Files.isDirectory(file)){
            isDirectory = true;
            setGraphic(new ImageView(folderClosed));
        }
        else{
            isDirectory = false;

            if (file.endsWith("txt")){
                setGraphic(new ImageView(genericText));
            }
        }

        if(!fullPath.endsWith(File.separator)){
            String value = file.toString();
            int indexOf = value.lastIndexOf(File.separator);

            if (indexOf > 0){
                setValue(value.substring(indexOf + 1));
            }
            else{
                setValue(value);
            }
        }

        this.expandedProperty().addListener((obs, wasExpanded, isNowExpanded) -> {
            if (Files.isDirectory(Paths.get(fullPath))) {
                if (isNowExpanded) {
                    imageView.setImage(folderOpened);
                } else {
                    imageView.setImage(folderClosed);
                }
                setGraphic(imageView);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> getChildren() {
        if (isFirstTimeChildren) {
            isFirstTimeChildren = false ;
            super.getChildren().setAll(buildChildren());
        }
        return super.getChildren() ;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf() {
        if (isFirstTimeLeaf) {
            isFirstTimeLeaf = false ;
            Path path = Paths.get(fullPath);
            isLeaf = ! Files.isDirectory(path);
        }
        return isLeaf ;
    }

    private ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> buildChildren() {
        Path path = Paths.get(fullPath);
        if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
            try {
                return Files.list(path).map(FilePathTreeItem::new)
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(FXCollections::observableArrayList));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    }

    public String getFullPath() {
        return fullPath;
    }

    public boolean isDirectory() {
        return isDirectory;
    }
}
```

I kept this fairly close to the example you borrowed from, though I don't particularly like much of his approach. I did clean up a lot of the event handling and brought some of it up to date (using lambdas etc). But really there is still way too much conversion between `String`s and `Path`s here: if you'RE building a Tree where each node essentially represents a `Path`, then you should use a `TreeView<Path>` and `TreeItem<Path>` etc, not continually convert everything between strings and paths.

Comment: if I change it with TreeItem<Path> it gives me more errors... and how can I set root as home directory? sorry but I'm new to javafx

Comment: It's quite a big refactoring to change it to be a `TreeItem<Path>`, though you end up with cleaner code (especially if you're not wanting to display the "computer" as the root of the tree, which technically isn't actually a path). But that is not the question you actually posted. You can get the user's home directory with `Files.get(System.getProperty("user.home"))`.

Comment: yes, I don't need the hostname to be the root, and as leaf I want my home + other directories

Comment: Again, that's not the original question you asked. If you have a new question, you should ask it. But you haven't tried to implement that, so you should try it first, and then if you get stuck and have specific questions, post those specific questions.

Comment: I give up, I'm going to choose FIleChooser for now